# C# Can not execute mysql stored procedure by Nhibernate

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, nhibernate

I don't know how to call stored procedure via NHibernate. So I searched and coded as below. But I got error

> OUT or INOUT argument 3 for routine is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger

**Stored Procedure:**

```
DELIMITER $$
USE ih$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ms_getDate$$
CREATE DEFINER=root@% PROCEDURE ms_getDate(OUT datetype VARCHAR(2))
BEGIN
    SET datetype = 0;
    SELECT a.Type into datetype 
    FROM hr_employees a WHERE a.Flag= '1';
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

**C#**

*NHibernate*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" >
  <sql-query name="ms_getDate"  callable="true" >
    <return-scalar column="datetype" type="String" />
    call ms_getDate
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

*Code*

```
public class At_InsertPlanningStoredProcedure
{
    public virtual int datetype { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
using (DbSession dbSession = new DbSession())
{
 try
  {
    IQuery query = dbSession.session.GetNamedQuery("at_insertplanning");
    At_InsertPlanningStoredProcedure a = query.UniqueResult<At_InsertPlanningStoredProcedure>();
  }catch (Exception ex){}

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the parameter and just return the value using:

```
CREATE DEFINER=root@% PROCEDURE ms_getDate()
BEGIN
    SELECT a.Type as datetype 
    FROM hr_employees a WHERE a.Flag= '1';
END
```

Currently, you have this as a parameter but when you call the procedure, you don't specify it.

As usual, if you have used the NHProfiler, you would have easily found it yourself.